# Assigne static file up-loader  value with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I try to get already exist file name in file up-loader but unable to get it.I have sample in 
jsfiddle what I try.
http://jsfiddle.net/shree/a4PKG/3/

But always file up-loader is empty when I click `GetImage`.Alert gives a correct length but  up-loader is empty.
Unable to find my mistake.Thanks.

Comment: Works fine man I am on osx lion safari!

Comment: @Tats_innit I am on firefox 12.0 and its not work.

Comment: Dosen't work in IE8 too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you an AJAX Update Panel in AJAX update panel file content length is zero if you are using update panel then remove the update panel and check.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are asking....If i'm wrong then please let me know....

http://jsfiddle.net/a4PKG/6/

Comment: Please see the new address...:)